# Регулярное выражение \W+ не находит символ "_" в строке

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Согласно [документации языка С#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#character-classes):

> `\W` - Соответствует любому символу, который не является буквенно-цифровым
>   знаком.

Мне казалось логичным предположить, что символ нижнего подчеркивания - "_" попадает под данное определение.

Но на практике оказалось, что регулярное выражение - `@"\W+"` не находит символ нижнего подчеркивания в строке - `@"@$^&#№_\|/*-+=~%{}()[];:,.!?`'"""`

Объясните пожалуйста, почему регулярное выражение, не находит символ нижнего подчеркивания -"_"?

Comment: Это очень кривой перевод, на самом деле, [`\W` находит любой символ, отличный от "словного"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#non-word-character-w), а вот что под этим подразумевается, там описано.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Под `\W` попадают все символы, кроме тех, что попадают под `\w`.

В C# под `\w` [попадают буквы](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#WordCharacter) (не `A-Za-z`, а все символы, из определенных категорий Unicode, включая кириллицу), цифры, и спецсимволы из категории [Punctuation, Connector](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pc/list.htm).

Символ `_` входит в категорию Punctuation, Connector (там кроме него еще десяток символов, вроде `﹍` и `⁀`).

Если проблема только с `_` - явно добавьте его в список символов: `[\W_]+`.

Если хотите захватить все Punctuation, Connector - добавляйте весь класс
 все не-бувкы и не-цифры - добавляйте весь класс: `[\W\p{Pc}]+`.

Answer (score 4):

И так, нужно вспомнить, что обратное метасимволу `\W` является `\w`, который можно записать, как `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` то есть, символ, который используется в словах.

Обычно он включает в себя все буквы, все цифры и знак подчеркивания `_`, исходя из этого, мы теперь знаем, что подчеркивание входит в группу `\w`, а метасимвол `\W` включает в себя все, кроме символов, определяемых метасимволом `\w`.

Поэтому в вашем случае можно записать выражение, как `@"[\W_]+"?`

Comment: а разве `\w` не включает все юникодные сивмолы - кирилицу, различные умляуты и т.д.?

Comment: @MaxU, точно, совсем забыл про умлауты, опадают, если вам есть что добавить, или исправить, можете сделать это)